# Creation of mailbox in Microsoft Exchange server 2013 using C#

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

I am trying to create a `mailbox` in Exchange server 2013 using C#

Using this [Reference](http://codingchris.com/2012/02/15/creating-exchange-2010-mailboxes-in-c/) I created a console application to create a mail box.
Initially I created `Active Directory` , using the credintials I tried to create mail box. but the below statment throws exception

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
```

throws exception

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidProgramException' occurred in Exchange.exe
>
> Additional information: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

Comment: Can you share some code? What is Exchange.exe?